# laravel unexpected 'all' from controller

Tags: laravel

I have a code below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\administrator;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\shop;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
      }
      public function index() {
        $sh = new shop::all();
        return view('admin.dashboard', compact('sh'));
      }
}
```

For some reason all is not recognied, I get - syntax error, unexpected 'all'

Comment: Sidenote, Model names should be **S**tudly**C**ase (or StudlyCaps, PascalCase; etc.; it has many names) to fit Laravel conventions. `shop` should be `Shop` (which is why the answer below says `Shop::all()` instead of `shop::all()`) 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `$sh = Shop::all()`. You don't instantiate it the Shop class yourself here.

Comment: You can also do `$sh = (new shop)->all();`

Answer (score 1):

Don't instantiate the class, use the static method:

```
Shop::all()
```

See the Laravel documentation in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-models